# migrate google anaylytics account into google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I used google anaylytics ua for traffic records on a website. Now I am switching to google tag manager cause I heard about that would be the better way. I don't want to loose my data I recorded so far. so I am asking how to integrate the data of my former google analytics account into the google tag manager.

I read some tutorials but in most cases it is not described in detail. so far I just made a container in tag manager and made a tag for googleanalytics. furthermore i made the configurations to mirror the information that was described in the original analytics .js code snippet like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

in the backend of the former analytics account are done some filters/ configs. do I really have to compare each of these filters/ configs to my config/filters in tag manager? is there anyway to import/export the data? is there maybe any possibility to link the data collected by the tag manager and the former analytics account? Maybe these datas are auto-linked to my new tag manager?

your help will be highly appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag manager is just a system to deploy tags to a web property. If you set it up with the current UA-XXXXXX identifier you should have data continuity. As to changing GA configuration, that should not be necessary as long as you replace old tags with new ones.

Comment: do i understand that correctly? the former google analytics account is still working and wont be replaced. the tag manager ist just the tool to create the code represented on the website? the new google analytics data is still linked to the old analytics account? and this backend still can/ has to be used?

Comment: Correct. Just be sure to avoid double reporting due to reporting via tag manager and the old embeded code in your web site. Google remomends a gradual migration.